# MapDB is thread-safe?

Tags: database, parallel-processing, thread-safety, mapdb

Is it true that the latest version of MapDB is thread-safe? I couldn't find anything concrete at Google and [their website](https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/db/) doesn't say anything about locking.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the code comments of the data structure you need, like  HTreeMap, or BtreeMap, they are both claimed as concurrent.